# Visa RSA keys length

Tags: rsa, pki

I just found that Visa public keys have odd length like 1408 bits. On the other hand found most crypto libs (OpenSSL, Bouncy Castle, MS crypto API, Java Card) require fixed keys length like 1024 or 2048. I can see that in theory RSA key can be of any length but I do not understand:
1) why would visa use strange key lengths
2) which of the above libs will work with 1408 bits keys
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The 1408 key is part of the Visa's EMV Public Key infrastructure.  It is basically used with smart cards (on-card chips).  The key size was chose because of the ability of the card to handle it (via an on-chip RSA accelerator).  There is actually a schedule of keys. The 1408 key is set to expire December 31 2022.  The 1024 key is already expired.

According to the emvco.com [faq](http://www.emvco.com/faq.aspx?id=38) they do not use x.509 but ISO/IEC 9796-2 digital signature algorithm. Bouncy Castle has a 9796-2 signer (org.bouncycastle.crypto.signers.ISO9796d2PSSSigner).  Card Contact has a lib and [tutorial](http://www.openscdp.org/scripts/tutorial/emv/index.html)

Comment: Hi,
Thank you very much for your response. Can you please explain if the RSA crypto operation (verifying the signature) with 1408 bit keys will work on most crypto libs. I can see that ISO 9796 allows part of the data to be embedded in the signature but the modulus is still 1408 bits so I am not sure if this will work. I think that either I am missing something here (i.e. part of the modulus contains signature) or I have to try it.